# Bootstrap 4 dynamic modal not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've a code in Bootstrap 3.3.6 with modal which works absolutely fine. But now i want to use this code with Bootstrap 4. I tried it several times, but it is not working. Can anyone tell me where should i make the changes to make it run with bootstrap 4. 
 Button: `<input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $row["b_id"];?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view-data" />`

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view-data").click(function() {
    var book_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      url: "select.php",
      method: "post",
      data: { book_id: book_id },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#book_details").html(data);
        $("#bookmodal").modal("show");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what "not working" means?  Thanks.

Comment: The modal is not showing up

Comment: make sure you are adding `popper.js` in scripts.

Comment: already added popper.js but still now working